# Table rows ending up on different pages

Tags: tables, longtable, texstudio

I have a large table and I have tried other techniques but the rows are ending up on different pages.

Below is the code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{ |p{2cm} | p{2.6cm} | p{2.4cm} |  p{2.1cm} |  p{2.2cm} | p{2.2cm} |}
\caption{Cloud Computing}%
\tabularnewline
\hline
Grid computing & Mainframe computer & Utility computing & Peer-to-peer & Agility & Application programming interface \tabularnewline \hline

Attack mode
 & Cloud computing is the result of evolution and adoption of existing technologies and paradigms.  & The goal of cloud computing is to allow users to take beneﬁt from all of these technologies, without the need for deep knowledge about or expertise with each one of them.  & The cloud aims to cut costs, and helps the users focus on their core business instead of being impeded by IT obstacles.  & The main enabling technology for cloud computing is virtualization  & Cloud computing also leverages concepts from utility computing to provide metrics for the services used.  \tabularnewline [.5ex] \hline

 Advantages  & 1- Cloud computing, or in simpler shorthand just "the cloud", also focuses on maximizing the effectiveness of the shared resources. Cloud resources are usually not only shared by multiple users but are also dynamically reallocated per demand. & 1- This can work for allocating resources to users. For example, a cloud computer facility that serves European users during European business hours with a specific application (e.g., email) may reallocate the same resources to serve North American users during North America's business hours with a different application (e.g., a web server).  & 1-This approach should maximize the use of computing power thus reducing environmental damage as well since less power, air conditioning, rack space, etc. are required for a variety of functions. With cloud computing, multiple users can access a single server to retrieve and update their data without purchasing licenses for different applications.  & 1- In the 1990s, telecommunications companies, who previously offered primarily dedicated point-to-point data circuits, began offering virtual private network (VPN) services with comparable quality of service, but at a lower cost. By switching traffic as they saw fit to balance server use, they could use overall network bandwidth more effectively.   & control packet arrives faster  \tabularnewline[.5ex] \hline

Disdvantages  & 1- While aspects of the Oracle Cloud are still in development, this cloud offering   & 1- They began to use the cloud symbol to denote the demarcation point between what the provider was responsible for and what users were responsible for. 2- Cloud computing extends this boundary to cover all servers as well as the network infrastructure
 & 1- On March 1, 2011, IBM announced the IBM SmartCloud framework to support Smarter Planet. 2- Among the various components of the Smarter Computing foundation, cloud computing is a critical piece. & 1- As computers became more prevalent, scientists and technologists explored ways to make large-scale computing power available to more users through time-sharing. They experimented with algorithms to optimize the infrastructure, platform, and applications to prioritize CPUs and increase efficiency for end users.
& 1- In July 2010, Rackspace Hosting and NASA jointly launched an open-source cloud-software initiative known as OpenStack. The OpenStack project intended to help organizations offer cloud-computing services running on standard hardware. \tabularnewline[.5ex] \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

I have also tried using `tabular` (as shown below) , the table is now joined but exceeding the page length.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Cloud Computing}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm} | p{2.6cm} | p{2.4cm} |  p{2.1cm} |  p{2.2cm} | p{2.2cm} |}
\hline
Grid computing & Mainframe computer & Utility computing & Peer-to-peer & Agility & Application programming interface \tabularnewline \hline

Attack mode
 & Cloud computing is the result of evolution and adoption of existing technologies and paradigms.  & The goal of cloud computing is to allow users to take beneﬁt from all of these technologies, without the need for deep knowledge about or expertise with each one of them.  & The cloud aims to cut costs, and helps the users focus on their core business instead of being impeded by IT obstacles.  & The main enabling technology for cloud computing is virtualization  & Cloud computing also leverages concepts from utility computing to provide metrics for the services used.  \tabularnewline [.5ex] \hline

 Advantages  & 1- Cloud computing, or in simpler shorthand just "the cloud", also focuses on maximizing the effectiveness of the shared resources. Cloud resources are usually not only shared by multiple users but are also dynamically reallocated per demand. & 1- This can work for allocating resources to users. For example, a cloud computer facility that serves European users during European business hours with a specific application (e.g., email) may reallocate the same resources to serve North American users during North America's business hours with a different application (e.g., a web server).  & 1-This approach should maximize the use of computing power thus reducing environmental damage as well since less power, air conditioning, rack space, etc. are required for a variety of functions. With cloud computing, multiple users can access a single server to retrieve and update their data without purchasing licenses for different applications.  & 1- In the 1990s, telecommunications companies, who previously offered primarily dedicated point-to-point data circuits, began offering virtual private network (VPN) services with comparable quality of service, but at a lower cost. By switching traffic as they saw fit to balance server use, they could use overall network bandwidth more effectively.   & control packet arrives faster  \tabularnewline[.5ex] \hline

Disdvantages  & 1- While aspects of the Oracle Cloud are still in development, this cloud offering   & 1- They began to use the cloud symbol to denote the demarcation point between what the provider was responsible for and what users were responsible for. 2- Cloud computing extends this boundary to cover all servers as well as the network infrastructure
 & 1- On March 1, 2011, IBM announced the IBM SmartCloud framework to support Smarter Planet. 2- Among the various components of the Smarter Computing foundation, cloud computing is a critical piece. & 1- As computers became more prevalent, scientists and technologists explored ways to make large-scale computing power available to more users through time-sharing. They experimented with algorithms to optimize the infrastructure, platform, and applications to prioritize CPUs and increase efficiency for end users.
& 1- In July 2010, Rackspace Hosting and NASA jointly launched an open-source cloud-software initiative known as OpenStack. The OpenStack project intended to help organizations offer cloud-computing services running on standard hardware. \tabularnewline[.5ex] \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

This is what i like to achieve

[image: Table example]

I have added the code for both tables in an online editor at this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/2348761ddxkrq) for more explanation. Feel free to edit.

Comment: `longtable`, *by design*, is meant to allow tables be split across pages. If you don't want that, there are [many other options for tables](http://www.ctan.org/topic/table).

Comment: @jon If I am using `tabular` it is joined but now its exceeding page length.

Comment: A `tabular` environment *cannot* break across pages; that's why you're getting a table that exceeds the size of the page block. In contrast, the `longtable` environment is *explicitly designed* to handle any needed page breaks if the table material is simply too long to fit inside the available page block. Aside: The `longtable` environment already contains code to center its material horizontally -- no need to encase it in a `center` environment as well.

Comment: Note also that individual cells cannot be broken across pages, which is problematic when cell content is very large (as in your case). Thus, your problem is more one of design, I think. That is, although `longtable` can be used to 'repeat' headers on each subsequent page, the amount of text you are putting in each cell makes the table an uncomfortable way to 'learn' the point(s) you are tyring to make.  It may in fact *hinder* intelligibility. I would consider using a series of `description` environments or something else.

Comment: ... My advice would be: consider carefully what you are trying to say, and how to present that information most effectively. When the text bits are all quite long, it's probably not going to be a table.

Comment: the question is: what do you need? or what do you want do?

Comment: how can we know where your longtable example is breaking across a page as we don't know how big your page is. a4? US letter? beamer? Please _always_ make all examples complete small documents that people can run to reproduce the problem. Putting a longtable in a `center` environment does nothing useful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am editing the tables in an online editor. Here is the [link](https://www.overleaf.com/2348761ddxkrq) to it. Kindly see if I am doing anything wrong. I hope it give more details about the problem. Thanks

Comment: No sorry that is not how the site works, please fix the examples in your question to be a complete small document that shows the problem. Also fix the text of the question to _say what you want to happen_ If the table is too big for a page, then either you need to allow it to break over multiple pages, or you need to make the page bigger or the table smaller, if making the table smaller you can make it contain less data or use a smaller font. _You_ have to say what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added a sample image of the table from MS Word. How can I achieve this in Latex?

Comment: you can't basically. No standard latex table package splits a table cell across a page.

Answer (score 3):

Please always post complete documents not just fragments.

[image]

LaTeX table packages do not break a cell over a page boundary, however it is pointless putting such long texts into such narrow columns, (and they need to be narrower to fit on the page) as they are not readable.

A possible re-organisation would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


\section*{Attack mode}

\subsection*{Mainframe computer}
 Cloud computing is the result of evolution and adoption of existing technologies and paradigms.  

\subsection*{Utility computing}
The goal of cloud computing is to allow users to take beneﬁt from all of these technologies, without the need for deep knowledge about or expertise with each one of them.

\subsection*{Peer-to-peer}
 The cloud aims to cut costs, and helps the users focus on their core business instead of being impeded by IT obstacles.  

\subsection*{Agility}
The main enabling technology for cloud computing is virtualization. 

\subsection*{Application programming interface}
 Cloud computing also leverages concepts from utility computing to provide metrics for the services used. 



\section*{Advantages}

\subsection*{Mainframe computer}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Cloud computing, or in simpler shorthand just "the cloud", also focuses on maximizing the effectiveness of the shared resources. Cloud resources are usually not only shared by multiple users but are also dynamically reallocated per demand.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Utility computing}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item This can work for allocating resources to users. For example, a cloud computer facility that serves European users during European business hours with a specific application (e.g., email) may reallocate the same resources to serve North American users during North America's business hours with a different application (e.g., a web server).  
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Utility computing}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item This approach should maximize the use of computing power thus reducing environmental damage as well since less power, air conditioning, rack space, etc. are required for a variety of functions. With cloud computing, multiple users can access a single server to retrieve and update their data without purchasing licenses for different applications. 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Peer-to-peer}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item In the 1990s, telecommunications companies, who previously offered primarily dedicated point-to-point data circuits, began offering virtual private network (VPN) services with comparable quality of service, but at a lower cost. By switching traffic as they saw fit to balance server use, they could use overall network bandwidth more effectively.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Application programming interface}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item  control packet arrives faster.
\end{enumerate}


\section*{Disdvantages}

\subsection*{Mainframe computer}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item While aspects of the Oracle Cloud are still in development, this cloud offering.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Utility computing}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item They began to use the cloud symbol to denote the demarcation point between what the provider was responsible for and what users were responsible for. 
 \item Cloud computing extends this boundary to cover all servers as well as the network infrastructure
\end{enumerate}

 \subsection*{Peer-to-peer}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item On March 1, 2011, IBM announced the IBM SmartCloud framework to support Smarter Planet.
\item Among the various components of the Smarter Computing foundation, cloud computing is a critical piece. 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Agility}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item  As computers became more prevalent, scientists and technologists explored ways to make large-scale computing power available to more users through time-sharing. They experimented with algorithms to optimize the infrastructure, platform, and applications to prioritize CPUs and increase efficiency for end users.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection*{Application programming interface}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item  In July 2010, Rackspace Hosting and NASA jointly launched an open-source cloud-software initiative known as OpenStack. The OpenStack project intended to help organizations offer cloud-computing services running on standard hardware. 
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```